# Redirecting a response to an HTTP 500 error handler, when an error is thrown

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

If some underlying component throws an error, how do I get to inform the express.js stack about it? I am using an underlying data access framework which occasionally throws specific errors (for instance, when a record is not found in the DB).

Does express.js offer a way to jump straight to a 500 error handler, and redirect the response to a corresponding page? Unfortunately, I do not see a direct way to use the standard express.js way (using a `next` middleware handler) unless maybe if I use try...catch everywhere, which is also a bit of overhead

Comment: How about res.send(500, { error: 'something blew up' }); ? or am I getting the question wrong?

Comment: If my data access component throws an error, it gets out of the scope of the current express router method. In the simplest case, it will cause node crash the app, unless I use try...catch everywhere

Answer (score 0):

Usually you don't redirect to a 500 page. What you do is let the exception propagate and node.js will do a 500 for you if an exception was thrown.

I have some related rules I follow. Maybe you'll find them useful:

- Never use try/catch in async code (like node.js). Errors are usually propagated through the first parameter of the supplied callback.
- If I need to return an error to the user, I do it using `res.send('Error', 500);`

Comment: I do not understand one thing. If some component down the line actually throws the exception (throw ne Error(...)), there is pretty much nothing that I can do in my router handler methods, to pass that exception forward, unless I use try...catch. Otherwise the exception will simply make node crash the app

Comment: In node.js, with a handful of exceptions (like the validator module) if you get an exception the app should be let to crash and the bug causing that exception should be fixed.

That is because most node.js modules do not throw exceptions so an exception in node.js usually indicates a bug in the code.

Comment: So it is more of a convention, right. If you want to propagate an exception, you simply pass it along using a "next" handler (if there is one). If you want to indicate a serious error, you throw it. Is this correct? This seems different from other environments, like Java, for example

Comment: You got it. Yeah, it's different. Java abuses exceptions anyway using them for everything and anything. :)

Comment: Thanks. Then, I guess, there is no general way to deal nicely with TypeError errors, like when trying to manipulate undefined variables? I will always need to do manual checks everywhere.

Comment: Yeah. That's JS world. Checks everywhere. From experience it gives you more robust code at the cost of verbosity which may impact how maintainable is the code.

Answer (score 0):

Something for those who are still looking for an answer like me:

1- Use express default errorHandler middleware

```
app.use(express.errorHandler());
```

Or

2- Supply your own error handling middleware:

```
app.use(function (error, req, res, next) {
            res.status(500);
            res.render("500.jade", {});
        });
```

Ideally you would want to use the first option on `DEV` and the second one on `PROD`

```
// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

app.use((function (error, req, res, next) {
  res.status(500);
  res.render("500.jade", {});
});
```

Note: the error handler should be strategically placed *below* the app.router